# Can we share test utilities between crates?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have crate-0 that has `src/lib.rs` as follows:

```
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test_utils {
    pub struct OnlyInTests(pub usize);
    pub fn helper() -> usize { 999 }

    #[test]
    fn test_0() { let _ = OnlyInTests(helper()); }
}
```

I also have crate-1 where I need the testing framework I defined in crate-0:

```
extern crate crate_0;

#[cfg(test)]
pub mod test_utils {
    // This will error out - cannot find mod test_utils in crate_0
    use crate_0::test_utils::{OnlyInTests, helper()};

    #[test]
    fn test_1() { let _ = OnlyInTests(helper()); }
}
```

The code here is trivial and can be copy-pasted, but in reality I have complex test utilities which I want to use while testing crate-1.

I cannot separate out the test utilities into a different crate as I would get cyclic dependency error: `test_utils` would depend on `crate-0` create stuff and `crate-0` would depend on `test_utils` for testing). Nor do I actually want to do this as there are further crates down the line whose testing utilities I would like to use in dependent crates.

Comment: Much better with the error message! Would defining the test utilities in a non- `#[cfg(test)]` guarded module be acceptable? (I am not it is necessary, just checking)

Comment: @MatthieuM. That will make it a part of the production binary - which is again not desirable (or did i not understand you ?)

Comment: It depends on your compilation mode (a static binary could strip unused stuff), but yes there is a risk it does make it into the binary so hopefully it can be avoided.

Comment: Can you break the cyclic link by putting some or all of the tests in the test-utils crate, rather than crate-0 depending on test-utils?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson maybe i could if i tried hard enough but that will lead to an explosion of crates i need to maintain - as said if this is doable then there are other crates i would like to extend this to. Currently i am using a custom feature for it, which is again not so ideal (causing combinatorial features explosion). Also i would lose the ability to test a crate as the testing would then be in a separate crate - so more elaborate CI setup would be required.

Comment: I don't think I have enough information for any more concrete suggestions. A more complete example of the type of test utilities/tests and explanation of why there are dependencies would help.  I can't see where any of the tradeoffs might be with this dummy example.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson here is one place where the actual test-utils is there for e.g https://github.com/maidsafe/safe_client_libs/blob/29975e054e7b3589344a4b09ec594599015c9b73/safe_core/src/utils/test_utils.rs . Now i don't want to move all the tests of `safe_core` crate out elsewhere just because i need to share that test-utils with other crates. You can imagine it in the given example too where crate-0::test_0 uses many other stuffs from crate-0. And there are many tests. So ideally wouldn't want to move everything over to a different crate (unless there is no other way).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions with sightly different trade-offs:

### Separate Crate for utilities

Put your test utilities but not your tests in a new crate `crate-0-testutils`.
Make `crate-0` dev-depend on `crate-0-testutils`; `crate-0-testutils` depend on `crate-0`; `crate-1` dev-depend on `crate-0-testutils` and depend on crate-0.

This does not create a circular dependency as the dev-dependencies do not get propagated. Because of the dev-dependency your tests in crate-0 can still use what is in crate-0-testutils.

This at most doubles the number of your lib crates if all your creates had such utilities.

### Use a testing-feature across all crates

Create a feature in the `Cargo.toml` of`crate-0` that does not depend on anything:

```
[features]
testing = []
```

And one in `crate-1` that depends on the above:

```
testing = ["crate-0/testing"]
```

Then make the first tests on each of the crates fail when the feature is not enabled, to make for an easier to understand error:

```
#[cfg(all(not(feature = "testing"),test))]
mod testusage {
    #[test]
    fn panic_without_testing_feature() {
        panic!("Please use the feature testing when running tests.\n\nUse: cargo test --features testing\n\n");
    }
}
```

Only compile the utilities when the feature is enabled by adding a guard for it:

```
#[cfg(feature = "testing")]
fn testing_utility() {
}
```

This only adds one feature in each crate regardless of how many testing features it depends on but has the downside of needing a special invocation of the tests.

Avoid adding this feature in any crate wide dependency declaration. Including the testing-feature from `crate-0` in the dev-dependency of `crate-1` where `crate-1` also has a normal dependency on `crate-0` results in cargo building `crate-0` with that feature even for the build target of `crate-1` even in release mode.

Comment: Wanted to add that at the time of writing (May 2022) this is an unsolved problem with no clear idiomatic solution as far as I could tell. [Here's a relevant issue on rust-lang/cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8379) highlighting the poor ergonomics of this.